# Subir Imagen Con Codeigniter y Ajax - No me carga

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagen

estaba siguiendo un curso de codeigniter - pero decidí salirme del camino y cambiar algunas cosas como lo que es agregar ajax al proyecto - entonces mi problema es el siguiente:

1- en mi primer proyecto(se recargaba la pagina)si podía guardar mi imagen, pero al cambiar a ajax ya no puedo guardarla y nose por que.

2- quisiera subir 5 imágenes, investigue algo, pero si no soluciono el primero problema, no puedo entrar al otro - ajunto mi codigo.
Cabe aclarar que todo es bd

Mi controlador con el que guardo y actualizo

```
 public function admin_saveproducto($product_id = null) {
    //echo json_encode($product_id);
    if ($product_id == null) {
        //Creamos el producto
        $data['producto'] = $data['codigoPro'] = $data['estado'] = $data['categoria'] =
        $data['moneda'] = $data['tipoCamb'] = $data['precioCom'] = $data['preciVen'] = 
        $data['descripcion'] = "";
        //Acccion
        $data['title'] = "Registrar Producto";
        $data['boton_title'] = "Registrar";
    } else {
        // editamos el producto
        $product = $this->Product->find($product_id);
        $data['producto'] = $product->producto;
        $data['codigoPro'] = $product->codigoPro;
        $data['estado'] = $product->estado;
        $data['categoria'] = $product->categoria;
        $data['moneda'] = $product->moneda;
        $data['tipoCamb'] = $product->tipoCamb;
        $data['precioCom'] = $product->precioCom;
        $data['preciVen'] = $product->preciVen;
        $data['descripcion'] = $product->descripcion;
        $data['title'] = "Actualizar Producto";
        $data['boton_title'] = "Actualizar";
    }
    if ($this->input->post()) {

        //El siguiente codigo hace referencia a la importacion validation
        //Orden :: nombre del campo :: nombre con el que se muestra el error ::Reglas de validaciones
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('producto', 'Producto', 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[100]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('codigo', 'Codigo', 'required|min_length[2]|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('estado', 'Estado', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categoria', 'Categoria', 'required');
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('moneda', 'Moneda', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tipocambio', 'T.Cambio', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('preciocompra', 'P.Compra', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('precioventa', 'P.Venta', 'required');
        //  $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Imagen', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('descripcion', 'Descripcion', 'max_length[500]');
        //salvar nuestro post, pero antes verificamos que nuestros datos cumplen con todas las reglas
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            //Nuestro form es valido
            $save = array(
                'producto' => $this->input->post('producto'),
                'codigoPro' => $this->input->post('codigo'),
                'estado' => $this->input->post('estado'),
                'categoria' => $this->input->post('categoria'),
                // 'moneda' => $this->input->post('moneda'),
                'tipoCamb' => $this->input->post('tipocambio'),
                'precioCom' => $this->input->post('preciocompra'),
                'preciVen' => $this->input->post('precioventa'),
                'descripcion' => $this->input->post('descripcion'),
            );
            //Registrar
            if ($product_id == null) {

                if ($product_id = $this->Product->insert($save)) {
                    echo json_encode('exito-insert');
                    //exit;
                } else {
                    echo json_encode('error-insert');
                    exit;
                }
                //Actualizat
            } else {
               if($this->Product->update($product_id, $save)){
                   echo json_encode("exito-actualizo");
               }else{
               echo json_encode("exito-no-actualizo");}
               // echo json_encode($this->Product->update($product_id, $save));
            }
            //Cargar Imagen
            $this->upload($product_id, $this->input->post('producto'));
            // }else{
            //      
            //echo json_encode('Error al guardar');
        } else {
            echo json_encode(validation_errors());
            exit;
        }


    } else {
        // Llamamos a nuestra funcion(helper) que se encuentra en (helper/Product_helper)
        $data["data_estado"] = estado();
        $data["data_categoria"] = categoria();
        $data["data_moneda"] = moneda();
        $view["body"] = $this->load->view("admin/admin/saveproduct", $data, TRUE);
        // $view["body"] hace referencia a la variable contenida en el template body
        //esta vista es de contenido de la variable body(admin/template/body) definido en el template siguiente:

        $this->parser->parse("admin/template/body", $view);
    }
     //Cargar Imagen

}
```

-Aqui la funcion de guardado - y redimensionamiento de la imagen

```
 private function upload($product_id, $product) {

    $image = "image"; //Nombre del input image
    //Nuevo metodo
    $product = clean_name($product);

    //Configuracion de carga
    $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/productos'; //ruta
    $config['file_name'] = $product; //nombre del archivo
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 5000;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    /* $config['max_width']         = 1024;
      $config['max_height']        = 768; */
    //cargamos la libreria
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload($image)) {
        //se cargo la imagen
        //Datos del upload
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        $save = array(
            'img1' => $product . $data["file_ext"]
        );
        //llamamos a la funcion upload(system/model/) y cargamos la imagen
        $this->Product->update($product_id, $save);
        //Redimencinar imagenen
        $this->resize_image($data['full_path'], $product . $data["file_ext"]);
    }
}

//Funcion para Redimencionar Imagen
function resize_image($path_image) {

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path_image;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    // $config['create_thumb']     = FALSE;
    $config['width'] = 500;
    $config['height'] = 500;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
}
```

Este es mi Ajax

```
$('#btn-create').on('click', () => {

var url_action = $('.frm-create').attr('action');
var datosForm = $('.frm-create').serialize();
// $('#btn-create').text('Enviando...').attr("disabled", true)
$.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    method: 'post',
    url: url_action,
    data: datosForm,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (respuesta) {
        if (respuesta === "exito-insert") {
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'center-end',
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Exito',
                text: 'Has Agregado Un Nuevo Producto',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            });
            $(".frm-create")[0].reset();
        } else if (respuesta === "exito-actualizo") {
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'center-end',
                type: 'success',
                title: 'Exito',
                text: 'Se Ha Actualizado El Producto',

            });
        } else if (respuesta === "error-insert") {

            Swal.fire({
                position: 'center-end',
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                html: '<h3>El Prodcuto No Se Registrado</h3>',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                 timer: 1500
            });

        }else {
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'center-end',
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                html: '<h3 align=center>' + respuesta + '</h3>',
                // showConfirmButton: false,
                // timer: 1500
            });
            //alert('" <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+respuesta+ '</div>"');
        }
    },
    error: e => {
        console.error({error: e});
    }
});
```

});

Mi vista es esta:

```
<div class="card shadow mb-12">

<div class="card-header py-3">
    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary"><?php echo $title; ?></h6>
</div>

<?php echo form_open('', 'class="card-body frm-create" enctype="multipart/form-data"  autocomplete="off"'); ?>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                $text_input = array(

                    'name'     => 'producto',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'id'       => 'producto',
                    'value'    => $producto,
                    'class'    => 'form-control',
                    'maxlength'=>  "100",
                  //  'onkeypress' =>"return soloLetrasNumeros(event)",
                );

                echo form_input($text_input);
                ?>
                <?php echo form_error('producto', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Estado:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                echo form_dropdown('estado', $data_estado, $estado, 'class="form-control input-lg"');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Codigo:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                $text_input = array(

                    'name'     => 'codigo',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'id'       => 'codigo',
                    'value'    => $codigoPro,
                    'class'    => 'form-control',
                );

                echo form_input($text_input);
                ?>
                <?php echo form_error('codigo', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-8 col-form-label">Categoria:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                echo form_dropdown('categoria', $data_categoria, $categoria, 'class="form-control input-lg"');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">


        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Cambio:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">

                <?php
                $text_input = array(

                    'name'     => 'tipocambio',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'id'       => 'tipocambio',
                    'value'    => $tipoCamb,
                    'class'    => 'form-control',
                );

                echo form_input($text_input);
                ?>

                <?php echo form_error('tipocambio', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Moneda:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">

                <?php
                echo form_dropdown('moneda', $data_moneda, $moneda, 'class="form-control input-lg"');
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="row" style="border-top: 1px solid #d6d9dc; padding-top: 13px; ">

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Precio Compra:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                $text_input = array(

                    'name'     => 'preciocompra',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'id'       => 'preciocompra',
                    'value'    => $precioCom,
                    'class'    => 'form-control',
                );

                echo form_input($text_input);
                ?>
                <?php echo form_error('preciocompra', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Precio Venta:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php
                $text_input = array(

                    'name'     => 'precioventa',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'id'       => 'precioventa',
                    'value'    => $preciVen,
                    'class'    => 'form-control',
                );

                echo form_input($text_input);
                ?>
                <?php echo form_error('precioventa', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row" style="border-top: 1px solid #d6d9dc; padding-top: 13px; ">

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Descripcion</label>

            <?php $text_area = array(
                'name'      => 'descripcion',
                'id'        => 'descripcion',
                'value'     => $descripcion,
                'class'     => 'form-control',
                'rows'       => '4'
            );

            echo form_textarea($text_area);
            ?>
            <?php echo form_error('descripcion', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    "', '"
                                     </div>');  ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<!------------------------------------------------------------IMAGENES INICIO------------------------------------------------------------------>
<div class="form-group">

            <?php echo form_label('Imagen', 'image'); ?>

            <?php $text_input = array(
                'name' => 'image',
                'id'   => 'image',
                'value' => '',
                'type' => 'file',
                'class' => 'form-control input-lg'
            );

            echo form_input($text_input);

            ?>


        </div>


<div class="row" style="border-top: 1px solid #d6d9dc; padding-top: 13px; ">

    <div class="col-sm">

    </div>


    <div class="col-sm">

    </div>


    <div class="col-sm">


    </div>


    <div class="col-sm">


    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">

    </div>

</div>

<!--------------------------------------------------IMAGENES FINAL-------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col">
            <?php /*echo form_submit('mysubmit', $title , 'class="btn btn-success btn-block"')*/ ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btn-create"><?php echo $boton_title ?></button>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <a class="btn btn-info btn-block" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'admin/admin_listProduc/' ?>">Cancelar</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

Comment: Hola que tal, creo que tu problema puede ser que estas enviando los datos como json, ve heste tuto, en el envía el formulario como FormData, creo es lo mismo que el serialize pero no lo conviertas en datos json: http://mfikri.com/en/blog/codeigniter-ajax-upload

Comment: Aqu{i también tienes algo parecido: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588004/7621631, yo he usado esos métodos con codeigniter sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Hay una libreria de gentelella que te puede servir, el cual puedes adaptar genialmente y ya viene incluido su ajax.

https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/

Nota: Cabe destacar que personalmente he adaptado ese template html a Codeigniter para un sistema de administración de usuarios.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, te invito a leer [answer], ya que aportar solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Comprendo, solo para aclarar dudas, en mi respuesta insito al usuario a acceder a ese link para verificar mi respuesta entorno a la recomendacion que le di para usar una libreria alli existente para subsanar sus dudas y utilizar la herramienta que el busca y le ayude a superar ese percarnce, sin embargo hechar un vistaso a las recomendaciones de como publicar respuestas.